# How can I apply this dependent dropdown lists code to 2 sheets instead of just one?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm extremely new to coding. I followed along a youtube video to make dependent dropdown lists for my spreadsheet. This works as expected for "Sheet1" as stated in the first variable, but I also need this to work on "Sheet2" and don't know how to do that. I also have an issue with the third dropdown, it only works if the cells are in plain text format, but I wanted to know if there's something I can change to make it work if the cells are in currency. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
    var mainWsName = "Sheet1";
    var optionsWsName = "Options";
    var firstLevelColumn = 3;
    var secondLevelColumn = 4;
    var thirdLevelColumn = 5;

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsName); 
var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(optionsWsName); 
var options = wsOptions.getRange(3,3,wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,5).getValues();





function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow()
  var c = activeCell.getColumn()
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName()
  if(wsName === mainWsName && c === firstLevelColumn && r >= 3 ){
    applyFirstLevelValidation(val, r);
  } else if(wsName === mainWsName && c === secondLevelColumn && r >= 3) {
   applySecondLevelValidation(val, r)
} 
  
  
} //end onEdit

function applyFirstLevelValidation(val, r){
  
   if(val === ""){
    ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
     ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
     ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
     ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === val });
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[1] });
    var cell = ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn);
   applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
}

}

function applySecondLevelValidation(val, r){
   if(val === ""){
    ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
     ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
    var firstLevelColValue = ws.getRange(r,firstLevelColumn).getValue();  
    var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] === firstLevelColValue && o[1] === val });
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[2] });
    var cell = ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn);
   applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
}

} 


function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();
```

Comment: For adding another sheet you will either have to remove the condition which checks the name of the sheet or add another variable with the name of the sheet and a second condition. But what exactly do you mean by "it only works if the cells are in plain text format"?

Comment: I managed to fix the first part. It works on all the sheets now except for 1, which I'm fine with. And for the second part, on the third dropdown, a $ value comes down, a price, and it doesn't work. It only works if I change that $ value to plain text instead of having it as currency.

Comment: I apologize, but I still don't understand what exactly do you mean by this. Do you have any images that can be of help?